# How to upgrade an UI from an existing UI with for example flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

I just finished my first Android Studio App with Kotlin. The Design/UI of the App is pretty lame, but works fine. Now I want to "upgrade" my UI with replacing/adding new Components that look better. I started reading about Flutter, but I only see tutorials where they start a complete new app from scratch. Since I got a working app, how can I simply only use the "design"-Options of flutter and let my source code be?

Im pretty new in this field, but got some C#-Experience but never did an App and since this is my diploma thesis, I just want to use all my resources so the App also looks professional in terms of UI-Design etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I simply only use the "design"-Options of flutter and let my source code be?

Vanilla Android uses XML, however as you are likely aware [*thats not how it works in flutter*](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-lay-out-my-widgets-where-is-my-xml-layout-file). Since the system is completely different, I wouldn't expect you can just "change look" without re-designing it entirely with flutter.

If wanted to use flutter, I would assume you would need to [add it incrementally](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app) (as mentioned in [Gizmo1337's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65479311/9063935)).

However if all you want is to update how your app looks, theres nothing stopping you from changing your existing XML style. I'd say it's probably pretty overkill to change to flutter if all you want is a new look.

Answer (score 1):

You can add flutter to existing android or ios app you can read [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app) more.

Comment: But in this case, they just added a module to their Android-application. Is this really the way I should integrate flutter with or is there another possibility, but thanks for the link.

Comment: Your answer was not helpful, I dont get why you still got an upvote to be honest.